# Update a column to have primary key

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a table without a primary key

Like this:

```
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
      "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
      + KEY_ID + " INT, "
      + KEY_CONTENT1 + " , "
      + KEY_CONTENT2 + " , " + KEY_CONTENT3 +" date, " + KEY_CONTENT4 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT5 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT6 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT7 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT8 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT9 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT10 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT11 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT12 +
      " , " + KEY_CONTENT13 +
     ");";
```

But i want to update the row **KEY_ID** should have primary key,where table has been created without primary key,can i able to update the table?,Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare column KEY_ID as Primary key

```
private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
  "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
  + KEY_ID + "integer primary key, "
  + KEY_CONTENT1 + " , "
  + KEY_CONTENT2 + " , " + KEY_CONTENT3 +" date, " + KEY_CONTENT4 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT5 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT6 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT7 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT8 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT9 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT10 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT11 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT12 +
  " , " + KEY_CONTENT13 +
 ");";
```

Comment: i created the table and it is in use....I want to update the column KEY_ID to primatykey

Comment: did u try this query: ALTER TABLE MYDATABASE_TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY (KEY_ID)

Comment: try this  ALTER TABLE MYDATABASE_TABLE ADD  KEY_ID primary key

Answer (score 0):

If u just want to alter 1 column and make it primary then try this
 ALTER TABLE MYDATABASE_TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY (KEY_ID)